# Need to get field value and if it doesnt end in '.jpg' or '.png' it gets deleted or store its id

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

I am moving data from a db to another, now I've ended up with a column supposedly hosting image links but some of which are just invalid urls which doesn't lead to an image. I need to run a query to fetch the value field and get its data and compare if it ends in '.jpg' or '.png' or '.gif' , if not delete it or else store it's id for later deletion. Just been reading about using php `strpos`

My current query for fetching all fields with some data in the value field is below:

```
$query = "SELECT id 
         FROM kosmos_module_articles_item_fielddefs 
         WHERE fielddef_id='29' AND value IS NOT NULL";
```

thanks,
Iain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL, compare the last four characters of `value` to the list of extensions you want to allow:

```
DELETE
FROM kosmos_module_articles_item_fielddefs
WHERE SUBSTRING(value, -4) NOT IN ('.png', '.gif', '.jpg');
```